# Topology Spaces with onto open map.

Tags: general-topology

0
down vote
favorite

Let $(,)$ and $(',\ ')$ be topological spaces. Suppose $:  → '$ is an onto open map that has the extra property that $′$ open in $'$ implies that inverse of $(′)$ in $X$ (i.e. $$ is continuous). Prove that if $B$ is a basis for $(,)$ then $ (B)=\{(  ):  ∈ \mathcal{B} \}$ is a basis for $\ '$. Here is what I did but I am not sure it is right:

1. Because $ ∈ \mathcal{B}$ is open then $()$ is open in $(B)$ or $X'=\bigcup (())$
2. $(_1) \cup (_2)=(_1 \cup _2)$ since $_1$ and $_2$ are belonged to $B$ then there exist $_3$ just that $_3 = _1 \cup _2$ so $(_1\cup _2)=(_3)$ belongs to $(B)$. Then $(B)$ is basis for $\ '$. Please help.
   Thanks

Comment: Your statement "0 down vote favorite" is incorrect.  Right now there are 2 downvotes, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to test that a collection $\mathcal C$ of open sets is a basis for some topology $\mathcal T$ is to show that:

> $\forall U \in \mathcal T$ and $\forall x \in U,~$ $\exists C \in \mathcal C$ such that $x \in C \subseteq U$

To this end, choose any $U' \in \mathcal T'$ and choose any $x' \in U'$. Then since $f$ is onto, we know that there is some $x \in U$ such that $f(x) = x'$. Furthermore, since $f$ is continuous, we know that $f^{-1}(U') \in \mathcal T$. But since $\mathcal B$ is a basis for $\mathcal T$, we know that there is some $B \in \mathcal B$ such that:
$$
x \in B \subseteq f^{-1}(U')
$$
But this implies that:
$$
x' = f(x) \in f(B) \subseteq U'
$$
and so we've found our required basis element $f(B) \in f(\mathcal B)$ that covers $x'$ but still fits inside $U'$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that each $f(B)$, with $B\in\mathrm{B}$ is open, since $f$ is an open map.

Moreover, since $f$ is onto, you have $f(X) = X'$. But $\mathrm{B}$ is a basis, so
$$
X = \bigcup_{B\in\mathrm{B}}B.
$$
Therefore,
$$
X'= f(X) = f\left(\bigcup_{B\in\mathrm{B}}B\right) = \bigcup_{B\in\mathrm{B}}f(B).
$$
Now, we have to show that $U:=f(B_{1})\cap f(B_{2})$ is the union of some elements of the form $f(B)$, with $B\in\mathrm{B}$. Since $U$ is intersection of open sets, $U$ is open. Hence, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ and hence is the union of elements in $B$. Since $f$ is surjective, $f(f^{-1}(U))=U$, where the left-hand side is the image under $f$ of some elements in $B$.